# PostgreSQL function execute query

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I want to run a SQL query if a condition is met, but I get the following error:

ERROR: a separate $ chain is unfinished in or near «$func$

my SQL query is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc()
RETURNS TABLE(dateticket date, timeticket time, userid integer, my_all bigint) AS
    $func$
    BEGIN
            IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(dateticket)) from tickets) = 1 THEN
               RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select t.*
               from (select distinct on (userid) dateticket, timeticket, userid,
               count(*) over (partition by userid) as my_all
               from tickets t
               order by userid, dateticket, timeticket) t
               order by my_all, dateticket, timeticket';
            ELSE
               RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select t.*
               from (select distinct on (userid) dateticket, timeticket, userid,
               count(*) over (partition by userid) as my_all
               from tickets t
               order by userid, dateticket, timeticket) t
               order by my_all DESC, dateticket DESC, timeticket DESC';
            END IF;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You start the function with $func$ but try to end it with $$. These must match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is actually not about the condition or anything in the function itself, but the syntax of the function creation. You start the function definition with `$func$` and end it with `$$`. This will not work.

Change the `$func$` to `$$` to fix the syntax.

Comment: @Ivan It should be when you execute the function

Answer (score 0):

You have two fault in the function one is already answered the another one that the *RETURN* table's column is same as the columns name of the select query used inside the fucntion this will cause

> ERROR:  column reference "dateticket" is ambiguous LINE 1: (SELECT
>   COUNT(DISTINCT(dateticket)) from tickets) = 1 
>                                                      ^ DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column. QUERY:  (SELECT
>   COUNT(DISTINCT(dateticket)) from tickets) = 1  CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL
>   function myfunc() line 3 at IF
>   ********** Error **********

so you need to modify your function like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc()
RETURNS TABLE(datet_icket date, time_ticket time, user_id integer, myall bigint) AS
    $$
 BEGIN
     IF (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(dateticket)) from tickets) = 1 THEN
         RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select t.*
         from (select distinct on (userid) dateticket, timeticket, userid,
         count(*) over (partition by userid) as my_all
         from tickets t
         order by userid, dateticket, timeticket) t
         order by my_all, dateticket, timeticket';
     ELSE
          RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select t.*
          from (select distinct on (userid) dateticket, timeticket, userid,
          count(*) over (partition by userid) as my_all
          from tickets t
          order by userid, dateticket, timeticket) t
          order by my_all DESC, dateticket DESC, timeticket DESC';
          END IF;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```